# Kubernetes whitepaper

Tags: computer-science, kubernetes

Did Google publish a whitepaper on Kubernetes, of a similar style as [Borg](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub43438.html)?

I am aware of [end-user documentation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/) and it would likely explain a lot what I am looking for, but I find whitepapers easier to read than end-user docs. It's also easier to convert to dead-tree format and read in a single afternoon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [David Rensin's small book on Kubernetes](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub43826.html)? It is listed with other Google research papers, although it is more of an brief introduction/overview and less a whitepaper (like the [Borg one](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub43438.html)). It seems to be available still as a promotion from [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/promotions/kubernetes).

It is certainly worth reading and won't take long, but for getting a Kubernetes cluster running, you'll still want to dive deep into the end-user docs at some point. Good luck!

Comment: Great tip @rwe, do you happen to know if there is something such as a guide for the functional application developer? In other words, I'm given a business requirement such as a batching ETL app, but instead of the natural way of just picking a fw such as Spring Batch that is not cluster oriented I would like to know how to interface with the Kubernetes scheduling API etc

Comment: Camilo, I'm not aware of of specific Spring-focused Kubernetes documentation. There are good patterns to be learned from the [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples) area of the repo and, while still 'beta' in v1.1.x the [Jobs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/jobs.md) API may be valuable for some kinds of ETL. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

While not a white-paper, the ACM Queue article by some of the Kubernetes and Borg principals, [Borg, Omega, and Kubernetes: Lessons learned from three container-management systems over a decade](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2898444), is an interesting overview of the evolution of the infrastructure management and job-scheduling systems at Google.

In particular, the article calls out a shift in the domain abstraction level.  This trend towards "Application-Oriented Infrastructure" focuses on applications rather than machines.  Additionally, the article references an technical evolution from centralized "orchestration" to decentralized "choreography":

> The design of Kubernetes as a combination of microservices and small
>   control loops is an example of control through choreography—achieving
>   a desired emergent behavior by combining the effects of separate,
>   autonomous entities that collaborate.

Check it out!